# FileNotFound Exception on Accesing PHP file in Android

Tags: android, httpclient, filenotfoundexception

I am trying on Client/Server side application in android. I have a php file which simply get or post data. On Android I have an activity which get and post data from server file. I hav problem in accessing that file which is located on `c://xampp/htdocs/Project/server.php` and in android I have these lines of code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.178.10.54/xampp/htdocs/Project1/server.php");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
```

But when I run my app these lines of exception occurres :

```
04-09 16:18:21.484: W/System.err(7752):java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.178.10.54/xampp/htdocs/Project1/server.php
04-09 16:18:21.664: W/System.err(7752):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
04-09 16:18:21.664: W/System.err(7752):     at com.android.ServerInterface.executeHttpRequest(ServerInterface.java:111)
04-09 16:18:21.664: W/System.err(7752):     at com.android.ServerInterface.getAnimalList(ServerInterface.java:60)
04-09 16:18:21.664: W/System.err(7752):     at com.android.AndroidListClient$GetListTask.doInBackground(AndroidListClient.java:106)
04-09 16:18:21.664: W/System.err(7752):     at com.android.AndroidListClient$GetListTask.doInBackground(AndroidListClient.java:1)
```

Comment: open this in browser(chrome,internet explorar): http://192.168.10.54/xampp/htdocs/Project1/server.php tell us what heppend..

Comment: Url like http://192.178.10.54/Project1/server.php

Comment: @NiravRanpara yes it was 192.178.10.54/Project1/server.php.. thanks

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar thanks to you also

Comment: Don't think of it as accessing a php file. Think of it as accessing a resource on a server. What you're actually accessing is the product of the php file's execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.10.54/xampp/htdocs/Project1/server.php");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
```